# Does the InvocationContext propagate to the nested methods

Tags: java, ejb

I need to send to the nested methods prarmeter from the parent one

I defined an EJB interceptor and use it at the business methods level 
and I need in the nested method to know some information that should be send from the parent invoker method (non businesss data) that will be used in aduit
so, my question is , does InvocationContext propagate to the nested methods

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. As far as I know, the context is not propagated to nested methods, at least it did not work for me. If you have an active transaction (when using EJB, you probably have one), you might try to use a [TransactionScoped bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/TransactionScoped.html). Without transaction, you might try to define a custom bean scope (in CDI), but I did not try this. See a possible implentation for a TransactionScoped bean.

```
@SetAuditData
public void someMethod(String user, String foo...) throws Exception {

}
```

and the interceptor (which assumes for simplicity that the parameter is the first parameter, which is a String)

```
@SetAuditData
@Interceptor
public class AuditInterceptor {

    @Inject
    AuditTransactionalBean auditData;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object setAuditData(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Object[] parameters = ctx.getParameters();
        String user = (String) parameters[0];
        auditData.setData(user);
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

And a bean which holds the data (must be Serializable to be passivation-capable )

```
@TransactionScoped
public class AuditTransactionalBean implements Serializable {

    String data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data=data;
    }
}
```

This bean can then be injected in the nested bean/method.